# How to make external javascript link with variable version parameter (changeable parameter)

Tags: javascript, caching

I want other web sites to link to js file from my domain, like this:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://mySite/jsfile.js"></script>
```

To avoid the cache problem then I need to add a version parameter to the JS file.

But if the version parameter is static then they have to keep updating the link with every new version, so I need a "CHANGEABLE" parameter like this:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://mySite/jsfile.js?new Date().getTime()"></script>
```

How to do that?

**in other way: HOW TO MAKE THEM ALWAYS GET THE LATEST VERSION OF MY JS FILE WITHOUT THE NEED TO RE-UPDATE THE JS URL IN THEIR PAGES.**

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: there's probably better ways to do this, but https://jsfiddle.net/c55kkjch/ has worked for me in the past

Comment: why don't you link them to jsfile-latest.js and create other js files for your older versions?

Comment: You could make the ref. to a js script, which only call a api on your site, to receive the new version of the js, and include it on your site

Comment: `why don't you link them to jsfile-latest.js` how does this fix cache issues?

Comment: @JaromandaX , I think `new Date().getTime();` is just a value , it may not be that useful, in fact it can be replaced by anything. The useful part is `?`, i guess this is interpreted as query selector or cache buster & load file from server

Comment: yes, do you know what putting `?` does? the `new Date().getTime()` makes sure that you don't use a cached copy ... so, how does not having `?12344567....` fix the cache problem? answer, it doesn't

Comment: Will you consider using bundle tools like webpack or parcel.js to bundle your files, with a hashed name? Sometimes you might need the cache for performance, then when you want a different version of your logics, just publish a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a script, which call my api. Get the lastest js script code, And include it on site,

this way, it's doesn't matter if it's cached the url for the script.

First, Make a .js file, which use [Jquery getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) to get and execute. the script you won't have cached .

get the people to use this. then whenever the site is loaded, it get's a new version of the script from your server.

Jobs done.

Im not providing anycode, since, it's more or less using the Jquery getscript. and the docs for that, is better then any sample i could make.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your `<script>` tag with js:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://mySite/jsfile.js?new Date().getTime()"></script>
```

with:

```
<script>
    document.write("<script language="javascript" src="http://mySite/jsfile.js?k=" + Date.now() + "'><\/script>");
</script>
```

this way its posible to add some number or timesamp after your jsfile.

Comment: Thanks Edi, but the problem in this solution that it deletes all HTML content. Otherwise I shall read first the HTML content & add the linked JS file with timestamp to that HTML, then to write it all using  document.write. isn't there a simpler solution.